# Assigning a lot of variable on a convenient way

Tags: c++, class, object, optimization, variable-assignment

I'm working on a game. It goes quite well, now I'm making the playing field. Obviously, the program have to store the coordinates of the objects can be seen on that field. It means lot of objects.

At the moment, I do these assignments in the `main(){}` function. The problem is that if I want to make a lot of levels, a lot of assignments is necessary. In that case, `main(){}` would be unnecessarily long. I'd like to avoid that.

My only idea is to create array of objects like this:

`ClassName ObjectArrayName[NumberOfObjects]`

...which makes them easier to handle. But it still doesn't help to store coordinates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you assigning each position by hand??, why not to make a config file for each level and a LevelManager class to load them?

Comment: You can use *functions* to structure your code.

Comment: "... I'd be confused. I'd like to avoid that." : Too late. Perhaps some structure to your programming methodologies would be beneficial. Purpose-driven functions, data types, et'al.

Comment: :O Is your entire program in main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load your level data from a file. It's recommended that you use some kind of markup language instead of just reading plain text files. You could for example save your level data as a XML or YAML file. There exists plenty of libraries for reading these formats.

Comment: Is that enough if the XML file contains the code in C++ language? Can libraries read them then?

Comment: Umm, no. You should not write code into the markup language file. It should contain something like: <object><name>Boss</name><pos>5, 10</pos></object>

Comment: That's all? It doesn't sound difficult! =)

I'm gonna try to do something with it. I'm not sure that it's gonna work, depends on me. However, until...thanks for the answer.

Comment: Of course you have implement code that understands how to read the file. However this isn't too difficult. You should find plenty of examples with a little Googling.

Answer (score 1):

About the only lines you should have in main() is `Game myGame; myGame.Start();` :) As mentioned above, loading XML files to initialize your objects is a solution. But rather than doing it manually, try using [CodeSynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/). I've had good results with that.